# Angular filter by a property inside an array

Tags: javascript, angular

I have an observable resources$ that have this data:

```
[
    {
        title: "U1 - Poesía",
        tags: [
            {type: "module", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "comprension_lectora"},
            {type: "class", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "classroom"}
        ]
    },
    {
        title: "U2 - Test",
        tags: [
            {type: "module", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "another_module"},
            {type: "class", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "classroom"}
        ]
    }
]
```

And I want to create a new observable that doesn't have the tags with name: "comprension_lectora"

This is as far as I can get:

```
this.filterResources$ = this.resources$.pipe(
  map(resources =>
    resources.filter(resource => resource.title !== 'U1 - Poesía')
  )
)
```

But I don't know how to keep it going inside the tags property to filter the tags.name !== "comprension_lectora"

Answer (score 0):

Since resource$ is an observable, you might want to subscribe to that observable to get the results.

```
this.resource$.subscribe(
  (res) => {
    let data = res;
    let filter = [];
    for(let item of data) {
      for(let tag of item) {
        if(tag.name != 'comprension_lectora') {
          filter.push(tag);
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

This would be the raw for-loop process one can do. But with the new ES6 functions, I think this can be done better in lesser code lines. If somebody can help us with that, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of nested `for` loops or `if/else` conditional blocks, so here's my proposed solution.

```
this.filterResources$ = this.resources$.pipe(
  map(resources =>
    resources.filter(resource => 
      !resource.tags.some(tag=>tag.name==='comprension_lectora')
    )
  )
)
```

The `Array.some()` returns a boolean. When it encounters the first array item that returns `true`, `some()` breaks the loop and returns `true`. If all array items return `false`, then `some()` will return `false`.

Because we don't want resources that contain `'comprension_lectora'`, we throw a single bang in front of the boolean response.

If you're not a fan of these nested methods, you can extract the `some()` logic into its own private method so it looks a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe for that.

**component**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

export interface IItem {
  title: string;
  tags: ITag[];
}

export interface ITag {
  _id: string;
  type: string;
  name: string;
}

@Pipe({
    name: 'myPipe',
    pure: false
})
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: IItem[]): IItem[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return;
    }
    
    array.map(async (item: IItem) => {
      item.tags = item.tags.filter((tag: ITag) => tag.name !== 'comprension_lectora')
      return item;
    });

    return array;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  items: IItem[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.items = [
      {
          title: "U1 - Poesía",
          tags: [
              {type: "module", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "comprension_lectora"},
              {type: "class", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "classroom"}
          ]
      },
      {
          title: "U2 - Test",
          tags: [
              {type: "module", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "another_module"},
              {type: "class", _id: "xxxxxx", name: "classroom"}
          ]
      }
  ]
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<p *ngFor='let item of items | myPipe'>{{item | json}}</p>
```

**Additional bonus**

You can make this pipe more reusable by adding a variable for your tag:

```js
export class MyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(array: IItem[], badTagName: string): IItem[] {
    if (!Array.isArray(array)) {
      return;
    }
    
    array.map(async (item: IItem) => {
      item.tags = item.tags.filter((tag: ITag) => tag.name !== badTagName)
      return item;
    });

    return array;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```html
<p *ngFor='let item of items | myPipe: "comprension_lectora"'>{{item | json}}</p>
```

Comment: don't forget to declare your pipe in your module - @NgModule({ declarations: [ MyPipe, ... ], ... })